# Проблема с обрещениям к таблице

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Это запрос к БД, на выборку сообщения, которые пользователь отправил другим пользователям.

Проблема в том, что мне надо достать имя и фамилию, а они находятся в другой таблице.Под именем(datacenter).

id_finish(id человека которому отправляется сообщения) это внешний ключ к полю id таблицы datacenter.

В datacenter есть поля name, surname, которые мне нужно как-то включить в этот цикл

То есть как мне сделать что-бы $row[4]; и $row[5]; имели name and surname с таблицы datacenter

```
    $select = mysql_query("SELECT id, text, avatar, id_finish,  FROM massage WHERE id_start = '$id'");

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select))
    {
  echo $row[0];
echo $row[1];
echo $row[2];
echo $row[3];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Соединение:

SELECT id, text, avatar, id_finish, name, surname  FROM massage m join datacenter d
on d.id = m.id_finish WHERE id_start = '$id'

Comment: что значит m и d?

Comment: Псевдонимы таблиц для краткости.